# Enabled Dev Hub for company org (Performance Edition), but cannot create scratch orgs

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I plan to move to Salesforce DX, my company uses Salesforce Performance Edition which should allow 200 Scratch orgs. I enabled Dev Hub then tried to create my first scratch org, but I got following error message:

```
ERROR:  The signup request failed because this organization has reached its daily scratch org signup limit.
```

Then, I checked the limits:

```
> sfdx force:limits:api:display -u DevHub
```

[image]

Seems the Maximum of daily scratch org(last line) is empty, don't think that is correct. According to the document, I'm an admin user of the org, so I just need to enable the Dev Hub and no extra configurations required. We still use Salesforce classic (not Lightning), not sure if that causes the problem.

Do I miss anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can subscribe to this known issue which is In review state https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mCfAQAU&title=unable-to-create-scratch-orgs-for-performance-edition-organizations

Answer (score 0):

This should now be fixed for everyone. If you're still seeing the issue, please contact Salesforce support. Sorry for the inconvenience!